# Unicorn error while hosting a Rails app with NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

All of a sudden my app stopped working and these are the last lines I am getting from

**unicorn.log**

```
unicorn worker[0] -D -c /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production: relocation error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: symbol CRYPTO_memcmp, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
E, [2013-02-28T18:32:49.240524 #23929] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 26634 exit 127> worker=0
I, [2013-02-28T18:32:49.240810 #23929]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-02-28T18:32:49.255824 #26647]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=26647
I, [2013-02-28T18:32:49.256438 #26647]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

and **production.log**

```
[...]
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

Last thing I did was a very little and inoffensive `cap deploy`, after the app stopped working I also try a `cap deploy:rollback` but the error is still there. I'm new to unicorn, what's going on here please?

Comment: It happened to me today. The problem was a syntax error in a controller. Check out the unicorn.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it was some kind of VPS failure, from my admin panel I saw that the CPU usage was at max for no reason, so I shut it down and then restarted it and now it is working again...

Comment: Rebooting isn't really a "solution" -- you don't know what caused the problem (or the CPU spike), so you can't prevent it from happening again...